# Spring Boot - Slow to start application on different connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm experiencing some weirdness with a Spring Boot application.

When I'm connected to WIFI A (my home network) or disconnected from the internet entirely, the application starts within 6 seconds.

When I'm connected to WIFI B (my work network) the application takes 1.5 minutes to start.

This is a simple Hello, world! spring application. The main class looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("START := " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("STOP := " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

I see that the START timestamp is printed at roughly the same speed, so it must be the SpringApplication.run. This is a bare class, so there is no spring configurations otherwise. Why would a change in WIFI connection cause such lag to start? I'm running it both using `mvn spring-boot:run` on Mac OSX

Comment: Smells like DNS reverse lookup.

Comment: Hm, any way to check if it is? So far, I can't seem to find anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Wireshark on your WLAN adapter and see what traffic goes out when you launch?

Comment: Does the 1.5 minutes include downloading all the dependencies via Maven? Does it *always* take this long, or just the first time?

Comment: Always. Running the jar alone also causes this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar problem to this. A very Simple Spring Boot app would take around 45 seconds to start on office network, and under 10 seconds on my home network.

It seems there was a delay identifying my external IP address, but running the following command fixed it on my Mac.

```
scutil --set HostName "localhost"
```

Answer (score 0):

@chrylis is correct, it was a DNS lookup issue. By changing my DNS resolving settings on my work internet, the startup time improved infinitely.

Now I wonder why spring boot is slower when there is a slow DNS resolver, or maybe is it a MacOSX issue?

Comment: I have this same issue.  Did you find any way to log the DNS name that it was actually trying to resolve?  I want to see if maybe I can just make an entry in `/etc/hosts`